# HTTP response with java class is different from the response in the browser android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i have problem with my rest. I use Volley library, but the results different from the response in the browser android ?

this is, ther URL =

```
https://assac.com/profilepicture?app_key=bpHANRATGW35hkHNMJA9ssMOnLog9l7l3IxXDGiv&session_key=LSDK4ARF0w8flNc8GCj8mvvKdctKnN68FKSKlKplhyAClNK2&page=1&limit=10
```

and this format in java

```
String url = Variabel.URL_PHOTO_PROFILE + "?app_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(Variabel.app_key) + "&session_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(session_key)
                + "&page=" + String.valueOf(Variabel.page) + "&limit="
                + Variabel.LIMIT_DATA;
```

full code :

```
private void getNewAllPhotoUserFromServer() {

        String url = Variabel.URL_PHOTO_PROFILE + "?app_key=" + Variabel.app_key + "&session_key=" + session_key
                + "&page=" + String.valueOf(Variabel.page) + "&limit="
                + Variabel.LIMIT_DATA;
        Log.v("new", url);
        queue_get_new_all_photo_user = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        sr_get_all_new_photo_user = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        DrawDataAllPhotoUser(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    messageRespone("Koneksi bermasalah");
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    messageRespone("Server Error");
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    messageRespone("Koneksi Timeout");
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    messageRespone("Ada masalah dalam mengambil data");
                } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    messageRespone("Tidak ada koneksi");
                } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    messageRespone("Koneksi Timeout");
                }

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return jsonParams;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
        };
        sr_get_all_new_photo_user.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                Variabel.MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS_NEWS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue_get_new_all_photo_user.add(sr_get_all_new_photo_user);

    }
```

the result from java is :

```
{
  "isSuccess": true,
  "message": "ok",
  "pageCurrent": "1",
  "pageTotal": 1,
  "itemsTotal": 2,
  "memberProfilePictures": [
    {
      "photoMemberId": "O6lXnljaVabh55dd08c87b59c55dd08c87b64255dd08c87b6e4e5cAv",
      "photoMemberIdMember": "LWC6MZOgIZxB559c5af5ca70c559c5af5ca7b2559c5af5ca855TiMPZ",
      "photoMemberStatus": 1,
      "photoMemberURL": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_08_26/1440549064367_medium.png",
      "photoMemberURLLarge": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_08_26/1440549064367_large.png",
      "photoMemberWidth": 480,
      "photoMemberHeight": 700
    },
    {
      "photoMemberId": "QNRiYnQKk8V755d931c44efcd55d931c44f07155d931c44f11efffVd",
      "photoMemberIdMember": "LWC6MZOgIZxB559c5af5ca70c559c5af5ca7b2559c5af5ca855TiMPZ",
      "photoMemberStatus": 0,
      "photoMemberURL": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_08_23/14402974122618_medium.jpeg",
      "photoMemberURLLarge": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_08_23/14402974122618_large.jpeg",
      "photoMemberWidth": 480,
      "photoMemberHeight": 269
    }
  ]
}
```

but result from browser is :

```
{
  "isSuccess": true,
  "message": "ok",
  "pageCurrent": "1",
  "pageTotal": 1,
  "itemsTotal": 4,
  "memberProfilePictures": [
    {
      "photoMemberId": "kmz9RnqQmi2I55f7bc9eb023955f7bc9eb02df55f7bc9eb0381v2PqG",
      "photoMemberIdMember": "LWC6MZOgIZxB559c5af5ca70c559c5af5ca7b2559c5af5ca855TiMPZ",
      "photoMemberStatus": 0,
      "photoMemberURL": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_09_15/14422990385762_medium.jpeg",
      "photoMemberURLLarge": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_09_15/14422990385762_large.jpeg",
      "photoMemberWidth": 480,
      "photoMemberHeight": 640
    },
    {
      "photoMemberId": "O6lXnljaVabh55dd08c87b59c55dd08c87b64255dd08c87b6e4e5cAv",
      "photoMemberIdMember": "LWC6MZOgIZxB559c5af5ca70c559c5af5ca7b2559c5af5ca855TiMPZ",
      "photoMemberStatus": 1,
      "photoMemberURL": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_08_26/1440549064367_medium.png",
      "photoMemberURLLarge": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_08_26/1440549064367_large.png",
      "photoMemberWidth": 480,
      "photoMemberHeight": 700
    },
    {
      "photoMemberId": "QNRiYnQKk8V755d931c44efcd55d931c44f07155d931c44f11efffVd",
      "photoMemberIdMember": "LWC6MZOgIZxB559c5af5ca70c559c5af5ca7b2559c5af5ca855TiMPZ",
      "photoMemberStatus": 0,
      "photoMemberURL": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_08_23/14402974122618_medium.jpeg",
      "photoMemberURLLarge": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_08_23/14402974122618_large.jpeg",
      "photoMemberWidth": 480,
      "photoMemberHeight": 269
    },
    {
      "photoMemberId": "WwJHWP9ZQWhr55f7bc849ecec55f7bc849ed9055f7bc849ee41P6Ebd",
      "photoMemberIdMember": "LWC6MZOgIZxB559c5af5ca70c559c5af5ca7b2559c5af5ca855TiMPZ",
      "photoMemberStatus": 0,
      "photoMemberURL": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_09_15/14422990125018_medium.jpeg",
      "photoMemberURLLarge": "https://assac.com/public/uploads/pictures/2015_09_15/14422990125018_large.jpeg",
      "photoMemberWidth": 480,
      "photoMemberHeight": 853
    }
  ]
}
```

so how to fix it ?

Comment: by the way, you know you can use `Uri.Builder` for that url, right?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems your `Variabel.LIMIT_DATA` is `2`, so the answer is different. Set it to `10` (as it is in your URL) and you should have the same results (maybe not the same order).

Comment: did you try to replace your variables with hard coded strings (from the URL) one by one to see where the difference occurs ? Or if you paste the full URL code instead is there the exact same result then ? Since I cannot see any code i can only guess ...

Comment: `String url = https://kamardagang.com/api/member/images/profilepicture?app_key=bpHANRATGW35hkHNMJA9ssMOnLog9l7l3IxXDGiv&session_key=LSDK4ARF0w8flNc8GCj8mvvKdctKnN68FKSKlKplhyAClNK2&page=1&limit=10";`

still 2 result

Comment: Ok that's confusing now. It's not the URL you posted in your question and is there is a difference between browser and java answer if you use exactly the same hard coded URL ? Log your response in the `public void onResponse(String response)` method before calling `DrawDataAllPhotoUser(response)`. Is there a difference ?